# relation between two tables fact

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

We have two Fact tables as below

Fact1

| DeviceKey | Datekey | TimeKey | CustomersIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 101532 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230101 | 230945 | 1 |
| 2 | 20230101 | 092409 | 2 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 142915 | 3 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 120024 | 1 |
| 3 | 20230102 | 161935 | 2 |

Fact2

| DeviceKey | EventDateKey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230101 | 092423 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230101 | 093412 | 12 |
| 1 | 20230101 | 213311 | 12 |
| 1 | 20230102 | 125503 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230103 | 081215 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 174523 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 180112 | 12 |
| 3 | 20230101 | 120412 | 2 |

Display the EventDateKey and EventTimeKey of Fact 2 table, which is greater than the maximum Datekey and TimeKey per device in Fact 1 table.
and result as below:

Result

| DeviceKey | EventDateKey | EventTimeKey | ErrorKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230102 | 125503 | 2 |
| 1 | 20230103 | 081215 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 174523 | 12 |
| 2 | 20230102 | 180112 | 12 |

How do I reach this conclusion?
By creating a view in the database or in SSAS Tabular?

Comment: Src code. Please format

Comment: The *Device 1* will not match since the max(TimeKey) is 230945 is greater than all EventTimeKey in Fact2

Comment: Correct and edited.

Answer (score 1):

Using `group by` to get the max_date, then an inner join to get the data needed

```
select f2.*
from Fact2 f2
inner join (
  select DeviceKey, MAX(concat(Datekey,TimeKey)) as maxdatetimeKey
  from Fact1 f1
  GROUP BY DeviceKey
) as s on s.DeviceKey = f2.DeviceKey and concat(EventDateKey,EventTimeKey) > maxdatetimeKey
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Octcuphq)

Comment: This query cannot return all results
It does not show the results related to device 1.

Comment: The Device 1 will not match since the max(TimeKey) is 230945 is greater than all EventTimeKey in Fact2 for this device

Comment: Maybe I did not express my meaning well
In fact, the maximum meaning is concat(DateKey, TimeKey)

Comment: Because TimeKey format is int, the following query is used
MAX(CONCAT(DateKey, FORMAT(TimeKey, '0######')))

Comment: And I have another question, if we want to see results that are two days or 48 hours past the maximum DateTime, what should we do for this? @SelVazi

Comment: And a performance question. This is a simplified example of our real work. Running this query takes about 30 seconds or more. What can we do to improve it?

Comment: About performance you will have to add some indexes on both tables

Comment: Can you give an example in this case?

Comment: one combined index on Fact1 (DeviceKey, Datekey, TimeKey), and other one on Fact2(DeviceKey, EventDateKey, EventTimeKey

Comment: What can be done about this?
And I have another question, if we want to see results that are two days or 48 hours past the maximum DateTime, what should we do for this? @SelVazi

Comment: It is indexed on the tables, but I still have this problem.